# What is the Story behind Jambudweep?

Tags: puranas, history, shloka, earth, cosmology

In this Shlokha, which talks about the geography of the Ancient India?

Sloka as follows:

> Jambudveepe Bharatha Varshe Bharata Khande

Here I got some different views from Different scholars consider it variously as either the 'Indian sub-continent' or the 'Asian continent'

However we can see, none of them come even close to the TRUTH!! Let me share some of the important scriptural references here for you:

- Markandeya Puraan describes Jambu-dvip- as being depressed above and below and broad in the middle just like a Globe.
- Srimad Bhagavatam points out that on Jambu-dvipa, night prevails diametrically opposite to a point where it is day and Sun sets at a point opposite to where it rises.
- Mahabharat describes the Universe as a series of shells divided in two by an earth plane called the Bhu-mandala; Jambu-dwip- is the central landmark on this plane.
- Jain and Buddhist cos- mologies indicate Jambū-dweep at the centre of Madhyaloka or the middle part of the universe, the place where Human-beings reside.

And last but not least, It describe Bharat Varsha or India as just ONE of the NINE divisions of Jambu-dweep? Jambudvipa was divided into nine varshas (geographical regions) of which one was Bharatha Varsha. The other eight varshas were Ketumula Varsha, Hari Varsha, Ilavrita Varsha, Kuru Varsha, Hiranyaka Varsha, Ramyaka Varsha, Kimpurusha Varsha, Bhadrasva Varsha.

My question was What is the real meaning of Jambudweep? These all 9 varsha's represent ancient time continents? or Nine Planets on our Solar system?

Answer (score 0):

According to the blog here, there are some scriptural descriptions of Jambudweep (especially that night and day appear together on it) that means it has to refer to at least the entire planet Earth or an even greater region of stars.

http://decodehindumythology.blogspot.com/search/label/Jambudweep%20or%20Pangea%3F

Comment: Blogs are not considered to be valid source here. You should cite some authentic sources